# imshow を含んだ subplots 関数の width_ratios が効かない

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

axs[0, 1]の高さをaxs[0, 0]の高さに合わせ，axs[1, 0]の幅をaxs[0, 0]の幅に合わせるために，以下のコードを実行しました．しかし，添付画像のようにaxs[1, 0]とaxs[0, 0]の幅が合いません．

`img_ax.imshow(..., aspect="auto")`とすると幅は揃いますが，axs[0, 0]画像の比率が元画像と異なってしまいます．

元画像の比率を維持したまま，高さと幅を揃える方法はありますか？

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

fig=plt.figure(dpi=200, constrained_layout=True)
axs:list[list[plt.Axes]] = fig.subplots(
    2, 2,
    gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[3, 1],width_ratios=[3, 1])
)
axs[1][1].set_visible(False)

im = Image.open("brightest.bmp").convert("L")
img_ax=axs[0][0]
img_ax.imshow(np.asarray(im)[::4,::4], cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

[image: output figure image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delft Viewさんの方法を試してみました．
たしかに，空白を調整することで幅を揃えることができました．しかし画像の縦横比と`height_ratios(width_ratios)`の組み合わせによっては写真のようにかなり不格好になってしまうこともわかりました．

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(dpi=120)
axs: list[list[plt.Axes]] = fig.subplots(
        2,2,gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[4, 1],width_ratios=[4, 1])
    )
axs[1][1].set_visible(False)

# Image
img_ax = axs[0][0]
img_arr = np.random.rand(480, 480)*255
img_ax.imshow(img_arr,cmap="gray",vmin=0,vmax=255)

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=1, hspace=0.2)
```

[image: test1]

---

引き続きネットを調べてみた結果，良い解決策が見つかりました．([Colorbar with AxesDivider](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_axes_divider.html))

`make_axes_locatable(img_ax)`により，`img_ax`に紐づいた`AxesDivider`が作られます．`append_axes()`により，指定した位置，サイズ，間隔で新たな`Axes`を`img_ax`に追加できました．

```py
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable # 追加インポート
fig = plt.figure(dpi=120)
img_ax: plt.Axes = fig.subplots(1,1)

# Image
img_arr = np.random.rand(480, 480)*255
img_ax.imshow(img_arr,cmap="gray",vmin=0,vmax=255)

# Right and bottom axes
num_append = 1
divider = make_axes_locatable(img_ax)
for _ in range(num_append):
    right_ax = divider.append_axes("right", size="35%", pad=0.4)
    bottom_ax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="35%", pad=0.4)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

`num_append`を変更すると，追加する`Axes`を増やすことができます．
例：`num_append=3`
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: まさしくスマートです。

Answer (score 2):

スマートな方法とは言えないですが，`constrained_layout=False` に変更して出力を見ながら `plt.subplots_adjust()` の設定値で余白を調整してみました。詳細は [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) を参照ください。なお，デフォルト値は下記です。

```
left=0.125, right=0.9, bottom=0.11, top=0.88,
wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2
```

私の環境（macOS13(M1), Python 3.10.8, matplotlib 3.6.2）では，`wspace=0.4, hspace=0.3` で添付のレイアウトになりました。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

fig = plt.figure(dpi=200, constrained_layout=False)  # modified                     
axs: list[list[plt.Axes]] = fig.subplots(
    2, 2,
    gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[3, 1], width_ratios=[3, 1]))
axs[1][1].set_visible(False)

im = Image.open("brightest.bmp").convert("L")
img_ax = axs[0][0]
img_ax.imshow(np.asarray(im)[::4, ::4], cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=255)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image: レイアウトの画像]